# How to use M.S access in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want use access database in my project, this is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSqlDatabase m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    m_db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=c:\\db.mdb;");
     bool  ok = m_db.open();
    if(ok)
        qDebug()<<"ok";
    else
        qDebug()<<"not ok";
    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run it it shows mt ‘not ok’ I think I use wrong connection because QODBC driver in available, 
another question is where ‘db.mdb’ file must be located? in debug folder or it must be attached to the project and how the connection string should change ?

Comment: What does [`QSqlDataBase::lastError`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#lastError) say? I suggest you modify the code to print the error, then edit the question to show the new code and printed error.

Comment: It works with this connection string 

     m_db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=" + QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/db.mdb");

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't need to install anything regarding drivers If you need to connect to an MS Access database with Qt. But if you don't have the necessary driver you should build it on your own.

You can connect to and MS Access database with something like this :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\path\\to\\myDB.mdb");

if(db.open())
  qDebug() << "oK";
else
  qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
```