# ODBC Issue in Red Hat linux release 6.9:

Tags: qt, redhat, unixodbc

## ODBC Issue

`The database reported an error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data Source name not found, and no default driver specified`

As shown as below, QT application trying to connect a database file of type DBF (`.dbf`), when we try to execute the application we got the above error.

```
QSqlDatabase db;
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

QString str("DRIVER={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)}; DBQ=/path/to/dbf/files");

db.setDatabaseName(str);

if(db.open())
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...// Failure
}
```

Referred the link (https://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01039.html) and followed the below steps:

1. The configuration files `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` are present with the appropriate content.
2. Exported the variables `ODBCSYSINI`, `ODBCINSTINI` and `ODBCINI` with  `/etc/odbc.ini`, `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and `/home/user/.odbc.ini`
3. From the same shell where we have exported the variables, tried to execute the application however encountered with the error "The database reported an error: `[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data Source name not found, and no default driver specified`

Please find the content of the `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`

#### `odbc.ini` file:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
TestODBC=MyODBCDriver

[TestODBC]
Driver=path/to/driver file
DataDirectory=path/to/where my dbf files resides

[Default]
Driver=path/to/driverfile
DataDirectory=path/to/where my dbf files resides
```

#### `odbcinst.ini` file:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
MyODBCDRIVER=Installed

[MyODBCDriver]
Description=ODBC Driver
Driver=/path/to Driver file

[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
```

Please provide any suggestion or solution to resolve the issue

Comment: did you rebuild QODBC ...1) Do you have freeTDS ..2)

Comment: What are your actual `$ODBCINI`, `$ODBCINSTINI`, and `$ODBCSYSINI` values? Note that the latter should point to the directory containing the first two files.

Comment: `odbcinst.ini` file is not correct. First stanza has wrong title, and `Trace` keyword doesn't belong there.

Comment: What ODBC connect string is QT app using to try to make the connection?

Comment: @TallTed
Values of `$ODBCSYSINI`, `$ODBCINSTINI` and `$ODBCINI` are `/etc/odbc.ini`, `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and `/home/user/.odbc.ini` respectively.

Connect string we are using in QT App as shown in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552302/how-to-use-m-s-access-in-qt)

Comment: @TallTed I meant to say Connect string usage in QT App is very similar as shown in above link.

Comment: @MohammadKanan we don't have freeTDS.

Comment: @SrujanB, ok I understand you using Qt, sometimes you need to build thge QODBC .. did you do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the followup details. Given what else you've said, `$ODBCSYSINI` should be `/etc` (or unset). Note that "similar to" settings generally don't help resolve specific issues like yours.

Comment: @MohammadKanan I have tried by building QODBC.. Still same problem.

Comment: @SrujanB, check carefully my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093807/qt-application-crashing-when-using-odbc-driver-macos/45491568#45491568

Comment: @SrujanB, ignore freeTDS related things in the post and try

Comment: @MohammadKanan 
Skipped step 1, step 2 as we have already installed and have tried step 3 and step 4 as you specified in the link, but this time getting another error `The database reported an error:  [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed`.
Note: for us there is no server and port.

Comment: @SrujanB, hmm again driver issue!https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2014/01/22/sqlallochandle-on-sql_handle_henv-from-linux-sqlncli-driver/